# Peak counting in serial Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, programming, sensors, interrupt

I want to count peak of photocell data with serial communication in Arduino.

Here is the question. My problem is when I count one of the peaks it continues the counting and doesn't stop counting. My project is count Michelson Morley fringes with a photocell and Arduino.

If somebody can help me with the coding part I would appreciate it.

Here is the code that I used:

```
int count=0;
int val;
int data;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  data=analogRead(A0);
  val=map(data,0,1023,1000,0);
  if(val>700) {
   count++;
  }
  Serial.println(count);
  delay(100);
}
```

This picture shows what I am trying to achieve:
[image: Counting the peaks]

Example Michelson Morley fringes:
[image: Example Michelson Morley fringes]

Answer (score 2):

keep in mind that since you used

```
delay(100)
```

your 'loop' code runs in 10HZ (10 times a second)
So, every time you are lighting on your sensor, if its for longer than 1/10 of a second, you are likely going through several instances of 'loop', in which the condition

```
(val>700)
```

is satisfied.

If you **know** that your peaks are going to take several loops, and only want to count each peak once- a simple way would be to make sure you dropped from the previous peak before incrementing the counter. you can achieve that with something like:

```
int count=0;
int val;
int data;
bool inPeak = false;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  data=analogRead(A0);
  val=map(data,0,1023,1000,0);
  if(val>700) {
     if (!inPeak)
     {
        count ++;
        inPeak = true;    
     }  
  }
  else 
  {
      inPeak = false;
  }

  Serial.println(count);
  delay(100);
}
```